# Change Docker nginx and Wordpress Upload Limits

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I dont know how to update big files on wordpress? I need to update the limits of nginx and wordpress upload limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best solution is two step update on configuration files

**1.Step is update configuration file for nginx image** such as `client_max_body_size.conf` and remount the nginx container

```
docker stop <nginx-container-name>
```

create a configuration file as above

```
nano client_max_body_size.conf
```

then add below configuration info

```
client_max_body_size 25m;
```

and save and exit the file. Then run the below script

```
docker run -d --name nginx-proxy -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    -v <path>/client_max_body_size.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf:ro \
    -p 80:80 jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

This code mount the container with new upload limits.

**2. Step is to change the upload limits of wordpress** as given below;

```
    sudo docker container exec -it <CONTAINER ID ?> bash

    nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

Then add below parameters inside between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` tags

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

After these updates, save and exit from this file. exit the container by using exit command. Then restart the container.

```
docker restart <docker name?>
```

**Note**: generally `nano` may not be installed on docker wordpress image before so you can use below codes in sequence to install nano on image.

```
sudo docker container exec -it <CONTAINER ID ?> bash
```

After this step you can install as;

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
```

then exit the container.

Alternative solution can be, after installing nano;

```
sudo docker container exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash -c "nano /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads/ini"
```

then put below info and save exit. Then restart the container.

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
```